# How/Where do we specify curl commands in graylog?

Tags: curl, graylog2, graylog

I recently got started with the graylog application(https://www.graylog.org) and I understand that we can get logs for a particular service/application using the GUI provided after we specify the below parameters -

- Relative/Absolute time
- Search query

and then we can download the output as .csv file.

I have already tried the above method out, and the problem I faced was that, if I had to obtain logs for every 1 hour interval for a period of 3 days, I had to manually change the time and download all the .csv files and arrange them (for easy retrieval purpose).

For now, I wish to use a different method to obtain the logs. I want to use curl requests as the input instead of the GUI. And I want the output to be a .csv file.

My Question Is - How/Where do we specify curl commands in graylog to get the logs?

I already know how to write the curl commands to obtain logs. I am not too familiar with the application and wasn't able to find WHERE or HOW I can use them.

Apparently there is some **Export API** option somewhere where I can insert curl requests but I am not able to find it. Please help out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try posting this question to the Graylog community forum.

Comment: I already did and got the partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here,
I had posted the same question in the graylog community forum and received the following answer -

> The 'Export API' can be found in System->Nodes->API browser.

A detailed discussion regarding the same can be found from the link below:
https://community.graylog.org/t/how-do-i-post-curl-commands-in-graylog/24595